# get document array inside collections in firestore (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following code, I seek to obtain the following a single document depending on the id

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {db} from "../Firebase"
import { collection, getDocs, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import ItemProduct from "../components/ItemProduct"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Container = styled.div`

`

function PageItemProduct() {

  const [ itemProduct, setItemProduct ] = useState([])

let { id } = useParams();
let { idProduct } = useParams()

useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchData(){
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, `category/${ id }/product/${idProduct}` )));
      let itemArray = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        itemArray.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
      });
      setItemProduct(itemArray)
      console.log(itemArray)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [idProduct])



 return (
    <Container> 
        <ItemProduct item= {itemProduct}/>
    </Container>
  
  )
}

export default PageItemProduct;
```

I get the following error.
"Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but category/M680J7hNdnGw8JZLmbwK/product/1S8YtahL4xeGrO7ELO3j has 4."

Answer (score 0):

solution method

```
  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchData(){
    const querySnapshot = await getDoc(query(doc(db, `category/${ id }/product/${idProduct}`)));
    if (querySnapshot.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", querySnapshot.data());
      setItemProduct(querySnapshot.data());
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
      }
      
    }
    fetchData();
}, [])
```